# Capture all between characters from list of complex strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a long list of complex strings from which I need to extract several values. I've been able to create RegEx for most of them, but there is one type in particular I'm having problem with. I've looked at several similar questions, but nothing I tried worked so far.

Here is the list:

```
malware = ['Mar 07 2023 17:15:00 abcd.manage.trendmicro.com CEF:0|Trend Micro|Apex Central|2019|AV:File quarantined|Trojan.Win64.SHELMA.SMB1|3|deviceExternalId=313 rt=2022-12-21 08:44:17 cnt=1 dhost=NB-SUPPORT TMCMLogDetectedHost=NB-SUPPORT duser=ACME\\\\john.smith act=File quarantined cn1Label=Pattern cn1=1814300 cn2Label=Second_Action cn2=1 cs1Label=VLF_FunctionCode cs1=Real-time Scan cs2Label=Engine cs2=22.580.1004 cs3Label=Product_Version cs3=14.0 cs4Label=CLF_ReasonCode cs4=virus log cs5Label=First_Action_Result cs5=File quarantined cs6Label=Second_Action_Result cs6=N/A cat=1703 dvchost=cpnlug.manage.trendmicro.com cn3Label=Overall_Risk_Rating cn3=0 fname=66e9f4d4-df39-488d-8cf8-bdcf5d890598.tmp filePath=C:\\\\Users\\\\emil\\\\Downloads\\\\ msg=NONAMEFL dst=10.18.13.90 TMCMLogDetectedIP=10.18.13.90 fileHash=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX deviceFacility=Apex One ApexCentralHost=Apex Central as a Service devicePayloadId=xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxx TMCMdevicePlatform=Windows 10 10.0 (Build 19044) deviceNtDomain=N/A dntdom=Client\\\\Notebook\\\\ ', 
'Mar 07 2023 17:15:00 abcd.manage.trendmicro.com CEF:0|Trend Micro|Apex Central|2019|AV:File passed|Trojan.Win64.SHELMA.SMB1|3|deviceExternalId=314 rt=2022-12-21 08:45:17 cnt=1 dhost=NB-SUPPORT TMCMLogDetectedHost=NB-SUPPORT duser=ACME\\\\john.smith act=File quarantined cn1Label=Pattern cn1=1814300 cn2Label=Second_Action cn2=1 cs1Label=VLF_FunctionCode cs1=Real-time Scan cs2Label=Engine cs2=22.580.1004 cs3Label=Product_Version cs3=14.0 cs4Label=CLF_ReasonCode cs4=virus log cs5Label=First_Action_Result cs5=File quarantined cs6Label=Second_Action_Result cs6=N/A cat=1703 dvchost=cpnlug.manage.trendmicro.com cn3Label=Overall_Risk_Rating cn3=0 fname=rev_shell.exe filePath=C:\\\\Users\\\\emil\\\\Downloads\\\\ msg=NONAMEFL dst=10.18.13.90 TMCMLogDetectedIP=10.18.13.90 fileHash=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX deviceFacility=Apex One ApexCentralHost=Apex Central as a Service devicePayloadId=xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxx TMCMdevicePlatform=Windows 10 10.0 (Build 19044) deviceNtDomain=N/A dntdom=Client\\\\Notebook\\\\ ', 
'Mar 07 2023 17:15:00 abcd.manage.trendmicro.com CEF:0|Trend Micro|Apex Central|2019|AV:File cleaned|TROJ_GEN.R002C0DKG22|3|deviceExternalId=315 rt=2022-12-21 10:20:31 cnt=1 dhost=NB-SUPPORT TMCMLogDetectedHost=NB-SUPPORT duser=ACME\\\\john.smit act=File cleaned cn1Label=Pattern cn1=1814500 cn2Label=Second_Action cn2=1 cs1Label=VLF_FunctionCode cs1=Real-time Scan cs2Label=Engine cs2=22.580.1004 cs3Label=Product_Version cs3=14.0 cs4Label=CLF_ReasonCode cs4=virus log cs5Label=First_Action_Result cs5=File cleaned cs6Label=Second_Action_Result cs6=N/A cat=1703 dvchost=cpnlug.manage.trendmicro.com cn3Label=Overall_Risk_Rating cn3=1 fname=aowect.dll filePath=C:\\\\Users\\\\emil\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Temp\\\\ dst=10.18.13.90 TMCMLogDetectedIP=10.18.13.90 fileHash=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX deviceFacility=Apex One ApexCentralHost=Apex Central as a Service devicePayloadId=xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxx TMCMdevicePlatform=Windows 10 10.0 (Build 19044) deviceNtDomain=N/A dntdom=Client\\\\Notebook\\\\ ', 
'Mar 07 2023 17:15:00 abcd.manage.trendmicro.com CEF:0|Trend Micro|Apex Central|2019|AV:Unable to upload file|TSC_GENCLEAN|3|deviceExternalId=316 rt=2022-12-21 13:37:42 cnt=1 dhost=NB-SUPPORT TMCMLogDetectedHost=NB-SUPPORT duser=ACME\\\\john.smit act=File cleaned cn1Label=Pattern cn1=1632 cn2Label=Second_Action cn2=1 cs1Label=VLF_FunctionCode cs1=Damage Cleanup Services cs2Label=Engine cs2=7.5.1184 cs3Label=Product_Version cs3=14.0 cs4Label=CLF_ReasonCode cs4=virus log cs5Label=First_Action_Result cs5=File cleaned cs6Label=Second_Action_Result cs6=N/A cat=1703 dvchost=cpnlug.manage.trendmicro.com cn3Label=Overall_Risk_Rating cn3=0 fname=Non confermato 184296.crdownload filePath=C:\\\\Users\\\\emil\\\\Downloads\\\\ dst=10.18.13.90 TMCMLogDetectedIP=10.18.13.90 deviceFacility=Apex One ApexCentralHost=Apex Central as a Service devicePayloadId=xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxx TMCMdevicePlatform=Windows 10 10.0 (Build 19044) deviceNtDomain=N/A dntdom=Client\\\\Notebook\\\\ ', 
'Mar 07 2023 17:15:00 abcd.manage.trendmicro.com CEF:0|Trend Micro|Apex Central|2019|AV:File quarantinedd|Troj.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF063|3|deviceExternalId=317 rt=2022-12-21 13:37:49 cnt=1 dhost=NB-SUPPORT TMCMLogDetectedHost=NB-SUPPORT duser=ACME\\\\john.smit act=File cleaned cn1Label=Pattern cn1=1632 cn2Label=Second_Action cn2=1 cs1Label=VLF_FunctionCode cs1=Damage Cleanup Services cs2Label=Engine cs2=7.5.1184 cs3Label=Product_Version cs3=14.0 cs4Label=CLF_ReasonCode cs4=virus log cs5Label=First_Action_Result cs5=File cleaned cs6Label=Second_Action_Result cs6=N/A cat=1703 dvchost=cpnlug.manage.trendmicro.com cn3Label=Overall_Risk_Rating cn3=0 fname=pumpkin-2.7.3.exe filePath=C:\\\\Users\\\\emil\\\\Downloads\\\\ dst=10.18.13.90 TMCMLogDetectedIP=10.18.13.90 deviceFacility=Apex One ApexCentralHost=Apex Central as a Service devicePayloadId=xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxx TMCMdevicePlatform=Windows 10 10.0 (Build 19044) deviceNtDomain=N/A dntdom=Client\\\\Notebook\\\\ ']
```

I need to create two captures. The first is the antivirus action, which is the value after `AV:`. For example:

```
AV:Unable to upload file
AV:Unable to delete file
AV:File quarantined
AV:File passed
```

I need:

```
Unable to upload file
Unable to delete file
File quarantined
File passed
```

and any other action that might occur

The other section is the name of the malware, which comes right after the action and is surrounded by pipes |:

```
Trojan.Win64.SHELMA.SMB1
TROJ_GEN.R002C0DKG22
Troj.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF063
TSC_GENCLEAN
```

and any other malware name that might occur.

And here is one of my failed attempts:

```
pattern = '(AV:)(?s)(.*?)\|'
a = [re.search(pattern,m) for m in malware]
print(a)
```

Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: There's no `AV=` in your text. You do have `AV:`

Comment: You should also escape the `|`, because that is a special character in regex

Comment: You need a non-greedy quantifier `.*?`, otherwise it will match until the last`|`. Or use `[^|]*` to match anything that isn't `|`. And you don't need `(?s)` unless you need this to match across lines.

Comment: @Barmar That actually helped a lot. The only thing is that the | also shows. I'm using this pattern:

(AV:)(?s)(.*?)\|

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Oh, man... so true. That got me some results now, but it's not precise.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thanks for the heads up on the AV=

Comment: You are muddling the question by having such a humungous example. Examples should be as small as possible while still illustrating the problem. Also, you should always include the complete desired result for each example. That makes the question easier to understand and is needed for those giving answers to test their code. I suggest you revise your example.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for your input, but I'm not sure what's so muddled about my question. The list is long, yes, but the example itself is pretty straightforward. I also include exactly what the output should be, if you read it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is the pattern you want, not sure if the pattern holds for all your data though:

```
pattern = 'AV:(?s)(.*)\|3\|'
var = [re.findall(pattern,m)[0] for m in malware]
var = [v.split('|') for v in var]
print(var)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'm actually looking for two distinct values. One is the antivirus action by itself, and the other is the virus name by itself. As it stands, your RegEx is giving me both, including the pipes. and the pesky number 3. I've updated my expression and am now using this (AV:)(?s)(.*?)\| but it's still returning the pipe at the end. I also need the virus name by itself, but that's proving to be way harder than I thought it would be.

Comment: In hindsight, this actually works, except that I'm using replace('|',''). Now, I'm left with the second part if would be so kind as to help.

Comment: If you print the var, you'll see both the action and the malware in the format [[action1, malware1], [action2, malware2]]

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest breaking down each line into a usable structure (e.g. a dictionary) and then use it for further processing.

For example

```
import re

parsed = [ line.split("|") for line in malware ]
for i, (ts,*parts,attributes) in enumerate(parsed):
    *ts,url,cef = ts.split(" ")
    parsed[i] = { "ts":" ".join(ts), "url":url, "CEF":cef.split(":")[-1] }
    parsed[i].update( zip(["brand","vendor","year","message","virus"],parts) )
    iAttr = iter(re.split(r'(\b\w+\=)',attributes)[1:])
    parsed[i].update( (k[:-1],v.strip()) for k,v in zip(iAttr,iAttr) )
```

*It looks like those lines are formed from an assembly of different sources using distinct separators (the pipe being used at the last level).  You can further break down each part as you see fit.*

output:

```
import json
for i,d in enumerate(parsed):
    print("at index",i)
    print(json.dumps(d,indent=4))
```

at index 0

```
{
    "ts": "Mar 07 2023 17:15:00",
    "url": "abcd.manage.trendmicro.com",
    "CEF": "0",
    "brand": "Trend Micro",
    "vendor": "Apex Central",
    "year": "2019",
    "message": "AV:File quarantined",
    "virus": "Trojan.Win64.SHELMA.SMB1",
    "deviceExternalId": "313",
    "rt": "2022-12-21 08:44:17",
    "cnt": "1",
    "dhost": "NB-SUPPORT",
    "TMCMLogDetectedHost": "NB-SUPPORT",
    "duser": "ACME\\\\john.smith",
    "act": "File quarantined",
    "cn1Label": "Pattern",
    "cn1": "1814300",
    "cn2Label": "Second_Action",
    "cn2": "1",
    "cs1Label": "VLF_FunctionCode",
    "cs1": "Real-time Scan",
    "cs2Label": "Engine",
    "cs2": "22.580.1004",
    "cs3Label": "Product_Version",
    "cs3": "14.0",
    "cs4Label": "CLF_ReasonCode",
    "cs4": "virus log",
    "cs5Label": "First_Action_Result",
    "cs5": "File quarantined",
    "cs6Label": "Second_Action_Result",
    "cs6": "N/A",
    "cat": "1703",
    "dvchost": "cpnlug.manage.trendmicro.com",
    "cn3Label": "Overall_Risk_Rating",
    "cn3": "0",
    "fname": "66e9f4d4-df39-488d-8cf8-bdcf5d890598.tmp",
    "filePath": "C:\\\\Users\\\\emil\\\\Downloads\\\\",
    "msg": "NONAMEFL",
    "dst": "10.18.13.90",
    "TMCMLogDetectedIP": "10.18.13.90",
    "fileHash": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "deviceFacility": "Apex One",
    "ApexCentralHost": "Apex Central as a Service",
    "devicePayloadId": "xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxx",
    "TMCMdevicePlatform": "Windows 10 10.0 (Build 19044)",
    "deviceNtDomain": "N/A",
    "dntdom": "Client\\\\Notebook\\\\"
}
```

at index 1

```
{
    "ts": "Mar 07 2023 17:15:00",
    "url": "abcd.manage.trendmicro.com",
    "CEF": "0",
    "brand": "Trend Micro",
    "vendor": "Apex Central",
    "year": "2019",
    "message": "AV:File passed",
    "virus": "Trojan.Win64.SHELMA.SMB1",
    "deviceExternalId": "314",
    "rt": "2022-12-21 08:45:17",
    "cnt": "1",
    "dhost": "NB-SUPPORT",
    "TMCMLogDetectedHost": "NB-SUPPORT",
    "duser": "ACME\\\\john.smith",
    "act": "File quarantined",
    "cn1Label": "Pattern",
    "cn1": "1814300",
    "cn2Label": "Second_Action",
    "cn2": "1",
    "cs1Label": "VLF_FunctionCode",
    "cs1": "Real-time Scan",
    "cs2Label": "Engine",
    "cs2": "22.580.1004",
    "cs3Label": "Product_Version",
    "cs3": "14.0",
    "cs4Label": "CLF_ReasonCode",
    "cs4": "virus log",
    "cs5Label": "First_Action_Result",
    "cs5": "File quarantined",
    "cs6Label": "Second_Action_Result",
    "cs6": "N/A",
    "cat": "1703",
    "dvchost": "cpnlug.manage.trendmicro.com",
    "cn3Label": "Overall_Risk_Rating",
    "cn3": "0",
    "fname": "rev_shell.exe",
    "filePath": "C:\\\\Users\\\\emil\\\\Downloads\\\\",
    "msg": "NONAMEFL",
    "dst": "10.18.13.90",
    "TMCMLogDetectedIP": "10.18.13.90",
    "fileHash": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "deviceFacility": "Apex One",
    "ApexCentralHost": "Apex Central as a Service",
    "devicePayloadId": "xxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxx",
    "TMCMdevicePlatform": "Windows 10 10.0 (Build 19044)",
    "deviceNtDomain": "N/A",
    "dntdom": "Client\\\\Notebook\\\\"
}
```

...

Comment: Hey Thank you for your answer. That was really neat I have to say. I have other similar tasks to automate, and I'll be using your suggestion. I voted you up but decided to go with the other answer because it was a bit more compact. But I'll definitely use your suggestion. Thank you!